# Can I use a cross reference in the caption figures?

Tags: floats, captions, tags

I tried to find solutions, but I was unable to find

I need to report in **chapter 11**, a figure contained in **chapter 7** and I want them to have the same image number.
I tried using the `\tag{\ref{}}` but I get an error:

```
Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here. \tag
```

for example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

**Chapter7**

```
\begin{figure}[!htb] %[htpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{\small chapter7} %% NUMBER FIGURE 1 <<---
    \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}
```

**Chaper11**

```
\begin{figure}[!htb] %[htpb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \captionof{figure}{\small chapter11} %% NUMBER FIGURE 1 ?? <<--       
   %\label{fig:test1}
    \tag{\ref{fig:test1}} <<==== ERROR
\end{figure}
```

[image]

I would like the same image with the same label to appear again in the second image, as is done with `\tag{\ref{equation..}}`the equations

------- **UPDATE PROBLEM** --------------

I encountered a new problem with caption inside the minipage, compared to the following code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.25\textwidth}
    \centering\raisebox{\dimexpr \topskip-\height}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
    \caption*{\figurename\ref{fig:test1}: test sx} %<<== **ERROR**
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item prova
        \item prova
        \item prova
    \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

the error created by compiling the file is:

```
Package caption Error: \caption outside float. \caption
```

Do you have any suggestions, please?

Comment: Regarding the updated problem: Since you're not employing a `figure` environment, both `\caption` and `\caption*` cannot work. Instead of `\caption*{\figurename\ref{fig:test1}`, you should write `\captionof*{figure}{\figurename\ \ref{fig:test1}`. (The `\captionof` and `\captionof*` macros are provided by the `caption` package.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\tag` command should be used solely for the purpose of creating equation "numbers". I put the word "numbers" in quotation marks since the argument of `\tag` need not be a number.

Since you're loading the `caption` package, you could use its `\caption*` macro to achieve your typesetting objective.

And, since you're using `figure` environments, there's no need to resort to `\captionof`; just use `\caption` (and `\caption*`, where needed).

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{chapter7} %% NUMBER FIGURE 1 <<---
    \label{fig:test1}
\end{figure}

\hrule

\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption*{\figurename\ \ref{fig:test1}: chapter11}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: your solution is very interesting, and i added a new problem to complete the original request.
I got used to using `\captionof` for needs in some parts of the book